# Is the proportionality characteristic of this function being carried on?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, graphing-functions

$A=kx$ is a directly proportional function,where $A^2=B^2+C^2$.Does it necessarily mean $B$ and $C$ both vary directly with respect to $x$? If not, under what condition is this possible?

Thank you in advance for your explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

No. If $B(x)$ is an arbitrary function bounded between $0$ and $\sqrt{kx}$, we can simply let $C(x) = \sqrt{kx - B(x)^2}$, and the conditions are satisfied. Your condition will need to restrict $B(x)$ to be linear if you wish for $B$ and $C$ to be proportional to $x$.